# Jenkins on Raspberry Pi

Tags: jenkins, plugins, raspberry-pi, offline

I installed jenkins on my raspberry pi and when I opened the jenkins page, the introduction page comes up. The weird thing was that it said that my jenkins is offline and I should configure a proxy. That's weird because my raspberry pi has an internet connection and everything works fine. But then I tried to download github plugin for jenkins and no plugin was installed successfully. This is the exception:

```
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to download from http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/github/1.25.1/github.hpi
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1172)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1678)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1876)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1652)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor65.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1124)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:792)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:789)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:647)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1536)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2943)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.download(UpdateCenter.java:1123)
    ... 7 more
```

But when I try to go to that site (http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/github/1.25.1/github.hpi) manually, everything downloads just fine. Any ideas why my jenkins cannot access internet and seems to be offline?